# Finding density function of random vector (density transformation)

Tags: multivariate-analysis, density-function, multivariate-distribution, transform

Let  $X_{i} \sim \operatorname{Ga}\left(\alpha_{i}, \lambda\right)$ independent with $\alpha_{i}>0$ fūr $i=1,2$. Furthermore it is known, that $V=X_{1}+X_{2} \sim \operatorname{Ga}\left(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}, \lambda\right)$ and $U=\frac{X_{1}}{X_{1}+X_{2}} \sim \operatorname{Beta}\left(\alpha_{1}, \alpha_{2}\right) .$

I now want to determine the density of $(U, V)^{\top}$

To do this I applied the (multidimensional) density transfrom theorem.

So I started by determining the inverse of $$g(U,V)= g(\frac{X_{1}}{X_{1}+ X_{2}},X_{1}+ X_{2}) $$

So I determined the inverse by solving for $$1)\space X_{1}= X_{1}+X_{2} \cdot \frac{X_{1}}{X_{1}+ X_{2}} = v \cdot u$$ $$2)\space X_{2}= (X_{1} +X_{2}) -X_{1}= v - v \cdot u$$
Which than gives me $g^{-1}(X_{1},X_{2})= (v \cdot u, v - v \cdot u) $

Then I calculated the Jacobi Matrix of $g^{-1}$.
So $$\det 
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{\partial g^{-1}_{1}}{\partial u}(x_1) &  \frac{\partial g^{-1}_{1}}{\partial v}(x_1) \\
 \frac{\partial g^{-1}_{2}}{\partial u}(x_2)& \frac{\partial g^{-1}_{2}}{\partial v}(x_2)   \\
\end{pmatrix}
= \det\begin{pmatrix}
v & u \\
-v & 1-u \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now I want to apply the density transform theorem but I am not sure how to get the function of the random vecotor $(U,V)^{\top}$, because there is no information that $U$ & $V$ are independent. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Cross-post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4385756/321264

Comment: The density transform theorem does not assume independence. The result will show you whether or not $U$ and $V$ are indeoendent.